# Loops, methods and Just some Novice Problems

Tags: java

I am writing a program that can recieve a bunch of numbers as a string and then use a mathemtical procedure to find a polynomial function for that sequence of numbers. I have been given two classes. well three. but two is important for this question. The classes are sequence and term as shown below.

Sequence :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Sequence
{
   // the numbers in the sequence
   private double[] sequence;

   // sets up sequence by parsing s 
   // the numbers in s will be separated by commas 
   public Sequence(String s)
   {
       sequence = new double[] {1, 4, 19, 52};
   }

   // returns sequence 
   public double[] getSequence()
   {
       return sequence;
   }

   // returns 1 * 2 * ... * (x-1) * x 
   public double factorial(double x)
   {
       for (double i=1;i<=x;i++){
            x = x*i;
        }
        return x;
   }

   // returns true iff all of the items on sequence are equal 
   public boolean allEqual(double[] sequence)
   {
       boolean checker = true;
       double first = sequence[1];
       for (int i = 1; i<sequence.length ; i++) {
           if(sequence[i] == first) {
               checker = true;
           }
       }
       return checker;
   }

   // returns a new array holding the differences between adjacent items on sequence 
   public double[] differences(double[] sequence)
   {
       double[] diffs = new double[sequence.length - 1];
       for(int i = 0;i<=sequence.length;i++) {
           diffs[i] = sequence[i+1]- sequence[i];
       }
       return diffs;
   }

   // subtracts from each item in sequence the effect of the term t 
   // implements Step 4 of the algorithm description on the project web page 
   public void updateSequence(Term t)
   {
       for(int i=0;i<=sequence.length;i++) {
         sequence[i] = sequence[i] - t.getCoefficient()*Math.pow(i,t.getExponent());
       }
   }

   // returns the next term in the simplest polynomial that generates sequence 
   // implements Steps 1-3 of the algorithm description on the project web page 
   public Term nextTerm()
   {
       double[] lastSequence = sequence;
       int steps = 0;
       while ( !allEqual(lastSequence)) {
          lastSequence = differences(lastSequence);
          steps++;
       }
       return new Term(lastSequence[1]/factorial(steps), steps); 
   }

   // returns the simplest polynomial that generates sequence and displays      the polynomial as a String 
   // implements the algorithm description on the project web page 
   public  Polynomial solveSequence()
   {
       // TODO
       return null;
   }

}
```

and Term:

```
public class Term
{
    // the term = coefficient * x ^ exponent
    private double coefficient;
    private int    exponent;

    public Term(double c, int e)
    {
        coefficient = c;
        exponent = e;
    }

    // returns the coefficient
    public double getCoefficient()
    {
        return coefficient;
    }

    // returns the exponent
    public int getExponent()
    {
        return exponent;
    }

    // returns the term as a String for display 
    // see the sample file for the layout required 
    public String display()
    {
       // TODO
       String tocompile="tocompile";
       return tocompile ;
    }
}
```

polynomial:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Polynomial
{
    // the terms making up the polynomial
    private ArrayList<Term> polynomial;

    // creates a zero polynomial
    public Polynomial()
    {
        polynomial = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // returns the number of terms in polynomial
    public int numberOfTerms()
    {
        return polynomial.size();
    }

    // adds a new term to the end of polynomial
    public void addTerm(Term t)
    {
        polynomial.add(t);
    }

    // returns the indicated term of polynomial
    public Term getTerm(int k)
    {
        if (0 <= k && k < numberOfTerms()) 
             return polynomial.get(k);
        else return null;
    }

    // returns polynomial as a String for display 
    // see the sample file for the layout required 
    public String display()
    {
        // TODO
        return "";
    }
}
```

I now need to use a method to perform certain actions over and over again. so basically. Repeatedly create terms and add them to the result until all the numbers on the sequence are equal. Get it to print out the polynomial so you can see the result. Call  allEqual, nextTerm, and updateSequence to achieve this most likely. I have written the allEqual, nextTerm, updateSequence(with extreme amounts of help from the awesome community here)

Also, i need to make a constructor so i can split a string which has numbers seperated by commas so string might be 1,2,3,4,5 and seperate it so i have just numbers, convert them to double and then store in an array called sequence. I dont know at all this can be done. I think String.split and Double.parseDouble might be something i can use but i dont know how to use it.

PLease help. 
I was wondering if someone can help me out with this method. i really have no idea where to start.

### Thanks guys,

Basically, the solveSequence method is suppose to perform the following steps over and over again till we get a polynomial that can describe our sequence of numbers.

The algorithm that i am trying to implement is iterative. Each iteration derives one term of the polynomial. For example, starting from the sequence of numbers [1, 1, 5, 13, 25]:

1) Repeatedly calculate the differences between adjacent numbers in the sequence, until every number in the sequence is the same:

[1, 1, 5, 13, 25]   ⇒   [0, 4, 8, 12]   ⇒   [4, 4, 4]

2) The exponent of the new term is the number of steps above, i.e. 2.

The coefficient of the new term is the number on the final sequence divided by the factorial of the exponent, i.e. 4/2! = 2. Thus the new term is 2x^2.

3) Subtract the new term from each element of the original sequence. From the first element subtract 2 * 1^2, from the second subtract 2 * 2^2, from the third subtract 2 * 3^2, etc. This leaves [-1, -7, -13, -19, -25], which is the sequence of numbers to start the next iteration.

The second iteration with this example yields the term -6x, and leaves the sequence [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]. Now all of the numbers in the sequence are the same, so the iteration terminates. The final term in the polynomial is the number on the final sequence, i.e. 5, and the complete polynomial is

2x^2 - 6x + 5

So solveSequence is supposed to use the methods allEqual, nextTerm, and updateSequence and then find out the whole polynomial and return it or print it.

Please help. Kinda desperate now.

Comment: As per my understanding you want to  perform some kind of action in a method which will create terms  and add them to  result.And u wanted to do it till all the sequence are same .So my suggestion is to iterate through the sequence   and check for the similarity in sequence .if found the break the loop .I mean Some kind of infinite loop

Comment: Hello. yes. I sort of understand that and am trying to figure out how i can actually write that. i am quite a novice. Anyway, What i really wanted to know is how to use String.split and Double.parseDouble in the constructor to seperate a string of numbers and then store in an array and convert to doubles. Please help in that issue.

Comment: Regarding spiriting you can achieve it by  String string="1,2,3,4" String[] parts = string.split(",");

Comment: instead of a "-" .. that would be a comma right? and how about storing them in an array and then parsing? i actually have no idea what that is.

Comment: Yes can you paste whole code I am getting error in polynomial solve sequnece this calss in my setup does not exit

Comment: um. I posted both classes. but there is another class called polynomial. I will paste that now. thankyou for your help.

Comment: I am getting the String s as a parameter and want to parse and seperate it. that code is also included in sequence class. Please help.

Comment: Please Check my answer regarding splitting .I used integer.parseint() if you want double you can use double version of that method

Comment: Yes. I understand. thats ok. no problems. i was wondering you can help with the solveSequence method? help a brother out?

Comment: Please Check the code i pasted .

Comment: Ok. and this is for solveSequence method? sorry. i dont really understand.

Comment: No it is for your spilting i am looking in to your solve sequence method but m not clear what u want to achieve

Comment: Oh. well. ill try to explain again. Please look at the question again.

Comment: Ok. I have tried to explain. Please tell me what you think the solution to this is?

Comment: i think Your solve sequnec method should be some thing like this

Comment: Ahmed please see my edited in answer  i  Hope it will help

Comment: In future Refrain from posting such long codes otherwise  it will be difficult for community to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String Args[]) {
    parse("1,2,3,4");
  }

  public static void parse(String s) {
    String[] parts = s.split(",");
    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : parts) {
      list.add(Double.parseDouble(string));
    }
    for (double d : list) {
      System.out.println(d);
    }
  }
}
```

i think Your solve sequnece method should be some thing like this

```
While(!allEqual(sequence))
{
do other operation 
}
```

all equal method should return the flag false or true depending on whether all are same in sequence or different 
As I saw your all equal method always returns true .Please write the logic in such a way that if all the elment are not same then it will return false.

Comment: So if i am getting string s as a parameter. I would just do the following:

String string= s;
String [] parts = string.split(",");
double.parsedouble(string);

and this will give me a array of doubles?
Sorry. I am a novice beginner and need help.